# Batch Coding - Choose command not returning the correct answer

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, cpu-architecture

I am trying to create a batch file which has two options:

1. Create a series of folders with custom names (defined by variables inputted by the user)

OR

2. Create the same as before except also, once completed, automatically
   copying all appropriate files to the appropriate folders in the
   structure.

The idea is that with this batch file I could keep my film projects (As I am a freelance filmmaker working with my brother) in exactly the same folder structures across all 3 of our computers. AKA a uniform Project folder structure can be implemented with a simple double click and a few variables to fill in, while in the case of option 2 any files found on a specified SD Card are also moved to the appropriate folders within the structure.

The actual xcopy commands and mkdir commands etc. work exactly how they are supposed to.

Since the different computers will be allocating different drive letters depending on what is already attached to the computer before entering the SD Card into the card reader, I will never know what the drive letter of the SD Card will be (from which the footage and images will be loaded onto the computers).

For example:
One computer could have an external hard drive in (of which we have a few) at the time of the SD Card being plugged in, while another may have  only the SD Card as an external device.

The code below is the complete `.bat` file including past code which I had tried but didn't work or needed to be excluded for some reason. I have some lines of code in comments so I know what I had tried in the past, these are obviously not meant to be used anymore.

```
:Menu
ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO OFF
TITLE Saborknight Productions - Project Creator
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO PRESS the appropriate number to select your task, or 3 to EXIT.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Create Saborknight Default folder Hierarchy within a project folder
::(Disabled)ECHO 2 - Create Saborknight Default folder Hierarchy AND copy ALL files from SD Card to the appropriate folder
ECHO 3 - EXIT
ECHO.
ECHO WARNING - Option 2 will delete the files from the Recording Device automatically. Secure the device before proceeding!
ECHO.
ECHO.
CHOICE /c 123 /n 
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 EXIT
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO :CREATE
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :CREATE
::End of Menu

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:CREATE
::Creates DIR Folder Structure as per Saborknight Productions Standard
ECHO OFF
CLS

::Variables Descriptor
SET /P project_name=Enter the Project Name: || SET project_name=NothingChosen
If "%project_name%"=="NothingChosen" (
    GOTO ERROR_PROJECT
    ) ELSE (
    GOTO CREATOR
    )

:ERROR_PROJECT
::If no Project Name is entered
ECHO Please enter the Project Name
GOTO CREATE

:CREATOR
::DIR Creator + Confirmation
::Videos DIR
ECHO OFF
MKDIR D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Footage
::Cut from above MKDIR -> \"Day 1"\%device_name%
::Images DIR
ECHO OFF
MKDIR D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Images\%device_name%
::Audio DIR -> Soundtracks
ECHO OFF
MKDIR D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Audio\Soundtracks
::Audio DIR -> Recordings
ECHO OFF
MKDIR D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Audio\Recordings
::Audio DIR -> Sound FX
ECHO OFF
MKDIR D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Audio\"Sound FX"
::Premier Project DIR
ECHO OFF
MKDIR D:\Dropbox\"Project Files"\"%project_name%"

ECHO The Folder Structure has been created
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO What would you like to do next?
Echo.
ECHO 1 - View Created Folder Structure
ECHO 2 - Go to Menu
ECHO 3 - EXIT
::Choice is invisible
CHOICE /c 123 /n
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 EXIT
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO MENU
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO VIEW
::End of CREATE

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:COPY
::Creates DIR Folder Structure as per Saborknight Productions Standard + Copying/Moving Files from a selected SD Card connected to the computer
ECHO OFF
CLS

:COPY_PROJECT
::Project Variable Descriptor
SET /P project_name=Enter the Project Name: || SET project_name=NothingChosen
If "%project_name%"=="NothingChosen" (
    GOTO ERROR_COPY_PROJECT
    ) ELSE (
    GOTO COPY_DEVICE_NAME
    )
::If True, Process continues

:COPY_DEVICE_NAME
::Device Name Variable Descriptor
ECHO.
SET /P device_name=Enter the Name of the Recording Device: || SET device_name=NothingChosen
If "%device_name%"=="NothingChosen" (GOTO DAMN_DEVICE) ELSE (GOTO DEVICE_DIR)

:DEVICE_DIR
::Device DIR Variable Descriptor
ECHO.
::Selecting the location of the SD Card of the Recording Device + Confirmation
ECHO Copy files from drive: E, F, G, H or I?
SET _drive=G
::SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
::CHOICE /c fgehi
::IF ERRORLEVEL 5 SET _drive=I
::IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET _drive=H
::IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET _drive=G
::IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET _drive=F
::IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET _drive=E
ECHO.
ECHO You have selected drive %_drive%:
ECHO.

::DIR Creator + Confirmation -> Only if Device Drive is successfully selected
::Videos DIR
ECHO OFF
MKDIR D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Footage\"Day 1"\"%device_name%"
::Images DIR
ECHO OFF
MKDIR D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Images\"%device_name%"
::Audio DIR -> Soundtracks
ECHO OFF
MKDIR D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Audio\Soundtracks
::Audio DIR -> Recordings
ECHO OFF
MKDIR D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Audio\Recordings
::Audio DIR -> Sound FX
ECHO OFF
MKDIR D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Audio\"Sound FX"
::Premier Project DIR
::ECHO OFF
::(Disabled for Testing)MKDIR D:\Dropbox\"Project Files"\"%project_name%"

ECHO.
CHOICE /c YN /m "Would you like files to be deleted automatically from the device? Press Y=Yes or N=No"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO NO_DELETE
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO DELETE

:NO_DELETE
::No Deletion once Copied from Device
::For Copying Videos
ECHO.
ECHO Copying Videos
XCOPY %_drive%:\DCIM\ "D:\Movie Projects\"%project_name%"\Footage\"Day 1"\"%device_name%"\" *.MOV *.mp4 /V /-Y
::COPY %_drive%:\DCIM\ "D:\Movie Projects\"%project_name%"\Footage\"Day 1"\"%device_name%"\" *.MOV *.mp4  
::ROBOCOPY %_drive%:\DCIM "D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Footage\"Day 1"\"%device_name%"\*" *.mov *.mp4 /mir /copy:DATO /np /eta /log+:"Log - Footage CopyOnly.txt" /nosd /nodd
PAUSE
::For Copying Images
ECHO.
ECHO Copying Images
XCOPY %_drive%:\DCIM\ "D:\Movie Projects\"%project_name%"\Images\"%device_name%"\" *.MOV *.mp4 /V /-Y
::COPY %_drive%:\DCIM\*.jpg;*.png;*.cr2 "D:\Movie Projects\"%project_name%"\Images\"%device_name%"\" /V /-Y
::ROBOCOPY %_drive%:\DCIM "D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Footage\"Day 1"\"%device_name%"" *.jpg *.png *.cr2 /copy:DATO /mir /np /eta /log+:"Log - Images Copy Only.txt" /nosd /nodd
PAUSE
GOTO SUCCESS_MSG

:DELETE
::Copying with Automatic Deletion once Copied
::For Copying and Deleting Videos
ECHO Copying and Deleting Videos
MOVE %_drive%:\DCIM\*.mov;*.mp4 D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Footage\"Day 1"\"%device_name%"\ /-Y
::ROBOCOPY %_drive%:\DCIM D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Footage\"Day 1"\"%device_name%" *.mov *.mp4 /mov /copy:DATO /np /eta /log+:"Log - Footage Copy Delete.txt" /nosd /nodd
PAUSE
::For Copying and Deleting Images
ECHO Copying and Deleting Images
MOVE %_drive%:\DCIM\*.jpg;*.png;*.cr2 D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Images\"%device_name%"\ /-Y
::ROBOCOPY %_drive%:\DCIM D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"\Images\"%device_name%" *.jpg *.png *.cr2 /mov /copy:DATO /np /eta /log+:"Log - Images Copy Delete.txt" /nosd /nodd
PAUSE
GOTO SUCCESS_MSG

:SUCCESS_MSG
::Only if all Copying/Moving and DIR Creation Processes are Completed Successfully
ECHO.
ECHO The Folder Structure has been created and files copied/moved
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO What would you like to do next?
Echo.
ECHO 1 - View Created Folder Structure
ECHO 2 - Go to Menu
ECHO 3 - EXIT
::Choice is invisible
CHOICE /c 123 /n
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 EXIT
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO MENU
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :VIEW

:DAMN_DEVICE
ECHO.
ECHO Please enter the Device Name, Re-entering the Project Name
ECHO.
GOTO COPY

:ERROR_COPY_PROJECT
::If no Project Name is entered
ECHO.
ECHO Please enter the Project Name
ECHO.
GOTO COPY_PROJECT
ENDLOCAL
::End Of COPY

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:VIEW
ECHO OFF
CLS

TREE D:\"Movie Projects"\"%project_name%"
ECHo.
ECHO Press any key to return to Menu
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO MENU
::End of VIEW
```

### The Problem

In this part of the code, the CHOOSE command wont choose the correct choice:

```
@ECHO OFF
CHOICE /c fgehi

IF ERRORLEVEL 5 SET _drive=I
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET _drive=H
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET _drive=E
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET _drive=G
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET _drive=F
Pause
ECHO.
ECHO You have selected drive %_drive%:
ECHO.
Pause
```

### The Evidence of the Problem being a problem

I tested the Batch file on two separate machines (One by remote access so that the two screens lay side by side) and can be viewed here: [Image of the Problem being a problem...](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tzcjrmz9b4ekgxo/CHOOSE%20Failure.png?dl=0)

Apologies for the dirtiest code in history with a complete overuse of comments. This was supposed to be a one night project which has turned into a month long project and I still haven't solved it!

Even a programming friend of mine cannot explain why it wont work.

All help much appreciated in advance!!!

Also any alternative suggestions to complete the described tasks above are definitely welcome, I love learning new code!

Saborknight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented here: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php

> By the way, in Windows NT 4 this won't work, since the SET command itself will set an errorlevel (usually 0)!
>   However, Windows NT makes it easy by storing the latest errorlevel in the environment variable ERRORLEVEL

This works for me:

```
@ECHO OFF
CHOICE /c fgehi

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 5 SET _drive=I
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 4 SET _drive=H
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 3 SET _drive=E
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 SET _drive=G
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET _drive=F
Pause
ECHO.
ECHO You have selected drive %_drive%:
ECHO.
Pause
```

Unless you know the proper ritual to ask the Microsoft gods for forgiveness, I would recommend you stay away from batch, it is a lot of trouble.

Even PowerShell is much less of a hassle.

Comment: That works! Thanks! Can I ask what other alternatives there are to batch? Batch is just the one language I learned so if there is a better language for these kind of operations (and any more advanced) I am definitely open. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, apparently I was wrong in why your script wasn't working (see Aacini's answer). I do not take back my comment about batch being bad however.

If I had to recommend only one language, it would be Python because it has an interactive interpreter (so you can try stuff one line at a time for example, great learning tool), but really any scripting language would work. Even Visual Basic or PowerShell (though I am not a great fan) are decent tools.

Comment: It had been stressed upon me whilst learning the choice command never to lay down errorlevels in the wrong order. They had to be from last choice to first choice for some reason i cannot remember. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a more in depth look into Python again, I tried it once but not with true focus or determination...

Answer (score 2):

Your program fail because `IF ERRORLEVEL n ...` "execute the command if the errorlevel is GREATER OR EQUAL than the number given", that is, you placed the IF commands in the opposite order. This works correctly:

```
@ECHO OFF
CHOICE /c fgehi

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET _drive=F
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET _drive=G
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET _drive=E
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET _drive=H
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 SET _drive=I
Pause
ECHO.
ECHO You have selected drive %_drive%:
ECHO.
Pause
```

May I suggest you a different, simpler method?

```
@ECHO OFF
SET option=0FGEHI
CHOICE /c fgehi

CALL SET _drive=%%option:~%ERRORLEVEL%,1%%
ECHO.
ECHO You have selected drive %_drive%:
ECHO.
Pause
```